# Is it possible to extract response body In Spring WebClient?

Tags: spring, kotlin, reactive-programming, webclient, spring-webclient

I want to intercept requests and responses with the body in Sprin WebClient. I'm unfamiliar with this technology and don't know how I should do it. My first idea was to use `ExchangeFilterFunction` and it is enough to extract the response body. When I want to get a response body I have a problem. This is my example code.

```
override fun filter(request: ClientRequest, next: ExchangeFunction): Mono<ClientResponse> {
    logger.debug { "Request: $request" }
    val receiver: InsertionReceiver<String> = InsertionReceiver.forClass(String::class.java)
    val requestBody = receiver.receiveOutputAsString(request.body())

    return next.exchange(request)
        .flatMap { response ->
            response.body(BodyExtractors.toDataBuffers())
                .doOnNext { dataBuffer ->
                    val extractedBody = StandardCharsets.UTF_8.decode(dataBuffer.asByteBuffer()).toString()
                    println(extractedBody)
                }
            Mono.just(response)
        }
}
```

When I'm using `doOnNext` or `flatMap` the code inside is not executed. If I use the `subscribe` method then I was able to extract the body but then the flow is broken and the whole request/response failed. Do you know how to solve this problem and do we have other possibilities to read request and response body in WebClinet?